# PHP update data from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

how to update selected data from dropdown to mysql (mysql update) using php?

```
<form>
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option>Maintenance On</option>
  <option>Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="update">Apply</button>
</form>
```

The i set column type to tinyint(1). basically just update 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `value` `0/1` in select `options`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $connct = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','password','database');
        $value = $_POST['maintenance_mode'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connct,"UPDATE table_name SET filedname = '$value'");
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="">
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option value="1">Maintenance On</option>
  <option value="0">Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks @Juno Fernando  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass 0 or 1 based on your selection. please refer the below code

```
<form action = "updateMode.php" action = "POST">
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option value = "1">Maintenance On</option>
  <option value = "0">Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="update">Apply</button>
</form>
```

here is the updateMode.php

```
$mode = $_POST['maintenance_mode'];

//My SQL DB update logic should be written here
```

Comment: Wont work. Form will GET send...

Answer (score 0):

1) Set value in option

```
<form method="post" action="filename.php">
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option value="1">Maintenance On</option>
  <option value="0">Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="update">Apply</button>
</form>
```

2) Use Update query in php

```
$mode = $_POST['maintenance_mode'];
$query = "UPDATE `mytable` 
          SET `maintenance_mode` = '$mode'
          WHERE `id` = $id";
```

Comment: Wont work. Form will GET send...

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST"> <!-- IF YOU WANT IT TO POST TO ANOTHER FILE THEN USE: action="filename.php" -->
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option value="1">Maintenance On</option>
  <option value="off">Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="update">Apply</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$maintenance = $_POST['maintenance_mode'];

//UPDATE DB HERE WITH VALUE

}
?>
```

I assume in this code above that you want to do an update in your database. I marked the line you can do it on and the value it should update it with is the value from the variable called "maintenance"

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` tag for your `option` elements.

```
<option value="1">Maintenance On</option>
<option value="0">Maintenance Off</option>
```

Then put `action` and `method` tags for your `form` element:

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST"> <!-- REPLACE FILE/DIRECTORY DEPENDING ON WHERE YOU PROCESS THIS SUBMITTED FORM -->
```

Then on your `update.php`:

```
<?php

    /* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE table SET maintenance = ?"); /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["maintenance_mode"]); /* BIND THIS PASSED ON DATA TO YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

    header("LOCATION:form.php"); /* CHANGE THE FILE NAME DEPENDING ON THE FILENAME OF YOUR FORM */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have made database connection already. Code mentioned will work

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){    
    $mode = $_POST['maintenance_mode'];
    $sql = "update tablename set maintenance_mode = '".$mod."' ";
    // tablename is name of mysql table where you want to update and maintenance_mode is name of table field to which you want to update.
    mysqli_query($sql);
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<select name="maintenance_mode">
  <option value = "1">Maintenance On</option>
  <option value = "0">Maintenance Off</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="update">Apply</button>
</form>
```

Note: mysql is depreciated further, try using PDO instead